# Cleaning raw data with multi-line header

Tags: python, pandas

I need to organize data that I import from an excel database, the problem is that it have a multiple line header with client info, followed by a lot of lines with payment information. I want to get data from the header and create a new column with the number of the contract and situation of the operation (they are both in the header) and put this information in every payment line, so i can then slice the dataframe easily.

I used to work with Excel, and what i did was create a formula with IF statements in a column that would identify the number of the contract in the header, if not found would copy the cell above.
My code identified one key string in a column an then get the contract value and the status from a pre defined distance between the cells. You can see it in my python for loop below.

The python for loop became too slow, it was the primary reason I abandoned excel, so i hope there is a faster way to do it in python.

I also tried to use the .where() function but i couldn't tind a proper way to get the contract and status information from the header.

the for loop i used was something like this:

```py
report = pd.read_excel('report_filename.xls', header = None)

for j in range(report.shape[0]):
    if str(report.loc[j,1])[0:7] == 'Extract':
        contract = report.loc[j + 1, 3]
        status = report.loc[j + 7, 1]

    report.loc['contract #', j] = contrato
    report.loc['status'] = status

# Here is the final version of the code i used:

report = pd.read_excel('report_filename.xls', header = None)
report['Contract #'] = None
report['Status'] = None

for i, row in report.iterrows():
    if str(row[1]).lower().startswith('extract'):
        report.at[i, 'Contract #'] = report.at[i+1, 3]
        report.at[i, 'Status'] = report.at[i+7, 1]

report['Contract #'] = report['Contract #'].ffill(axis = 0)
report['Status'] = report['Status'].ffill(axis = 0)


report = report[report['Status'] != 'Inactive']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use pandas.iterrows?

```py
import pandas as pd

report = pd.read_excel('report_filename.xls', header = None)
newreport = report
newreport['Contract #'] = ''
newreport['Status'] = ''

for i, row in report.iterrows():
    if row[1].lower().startswith('extract'):
        newreport.at[i, 'Contract #'] = report.at[i+1, 3]
        newreport.at[i, 'Status'] = report.at[i+7, 1]
```

Comment: Ir worked really well, thank you! I needed to make some changes, im going to post the final version of it